Why are comments being selectively and without notification removed?
Either remove the entire comment thread or keep them all. Why are only a few of them selectively being removed and others remaining there? It seems as if this concern was previously addressed after searching through the site so why is this still happening?
The comments on this thread were pretty obviously selectively removed. There was nothing rule breaking in my comments or the person who I was responding to’s comments. Both of them were removed. If the charge is that the comments were opinion based, a) almost every comment on this site seems to be opinion based, but more importantly b) the comments still up are clearly opinion based such as the one talking about how Occam’s razor is, in his opinion, a bad tool.

Does this answer your question?

Related, I sort of wish "no longer needed" comments would show up as flagged to the original poster. It's not unusual for me to self-delete my half of a thread and flag the other half. It would be nice if there was a way (besides leaving them a comment and hoping they act on it) to encourage the other party to also self-delete their side.
